# I need to pull the text of an image file name from an array but am only getting "pyimage#" or "tkinter.PhotoImage object at X" as replies

Tags: arrays, image, variables, tkinter, filenames

I'm trying to create an array with an assortment of different randomized image files in it to display on a set of buttons in Tkinter. When a given button is clicked I'd like to add the text of that file's name to a new array. Basically, when button with imageX is clicked add "imageX" to a new array.

Unfortunately, I always get a return that isn't the image's filename, or the variable that I've set to correspond to that image, but instead either:

- "tkinter.PhotoImage object at X" (where is X is a location like "0x0000020FC894D2E0") if the command is populationbeta.append (population[0])
  or
- "pyimage#" (where # is an integer that seems to relate to the number of images in the source file), if I change the command to populationbeta.append (str(population[0]))

I feel like there should be a simple way of doing this and I've tried every work around I can think of but I'm not getting it to work. Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

Here's a shortened/simplified version of the code in question:

```
master=tkinter.Tk()
master.title("Not working")

a1b1c1 = PhotoImage(file = r"C:/users/jdavis319/documents/bushesoflove/BoLdraw/a1b1c1.png")
a1b1c2 = PhotoImage(file = r"C:/users/jdavis319/documents/bushesoflove/BoLdraw/a1b1c2.png")
a1b1c3 = PhotoImage(file = r"C:/users/jdavis319/documents/bushesoflove/BoLdraw/a1b1c3.png")
a1b2c1 = PhotoImage(file = r"C:/users/jdavis319/documents/bushesoflove/BoLdraw/a1b2c1.png")
a1b2c2 = PhotoImage(file = r"C:/users/jdavis319/documents/bushesoflove/BoLdraw/a1b2c2.png")

population = [a1b1c1, a1b1c2, a1b1c3, a1b2c1, a1b2c2]

populationbeta = []

populationbeta.append(population[0])

print(populationbeta)
```

This gives the result: "[<tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x000001A419D4F070>]"

Comment: You can actually do this in couple of lines or more(the entire code). Basically use `a1b1c1.cget('file')`.

Answer (score 0):

> This gives the result: "[<tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x000001A419D4F070>]"

Correct. That shows that you have a list of `PhotoImage` objects. If you want the filenames you can use `.cget('file')` on the objects. `cget` is a common tkinter method for getting the value of a configured option.

```
filenames = [image.cget('filename') for image in population]
```

Or, if you don't want to use a list comprehension to create a list of filenames, you can do it on an individual image like so:

```
populationbeta.append(population[0].cget("file"))
```

Comment: That works! Thanks so much! It does give me the entire address for the file - I don't suppose there's any simple way to pull out just the pertinent part of the filename without just going through the whole string and extracting the last characters?

Comment: @JasDavis: yes, it's simple. See [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Answer (score 0):

> This gives the result: "[<tkinter.PhotoImage object at
> 0x000001A419D4F070>]"

Absolutely. Now you want to population images.

Problem can be fix

Create looping for population images.

There are no minor change except `png`.
Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()
master.title("It is working now!")

a1b1c1 = tk.PhotoImage(file = "p1.png")
a1b1c2 = tk.PhotoImage(file = "p2.png")
a1b1c3 = tk.PhotoImage(file = "p3.png")
a1b2c1 = tk.PhotoImage(file = "p4.png")
a1b2c2 = tk.PhotoImage(file = "p6.png")

population = [a1b1c1, a1b1c2, a1b1c3, a1b2c1, a1b2c2]

populationbeta = []

populationbeta.append(population[0])

for i in range(len(population)):
    label = tk.Label(master, image=population[i])
    label.pack()


print(populationbeta)

if __name__=="__main__":
    master.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]